# I have an Australian travel document for refugees. Do I need a visa to travel to USA?

Tags: visas, usa, refugees

I have an Australian travel document for refugees. Do I need a visa to travel to USA ? If I need, can I apply for a visa ?

Comment: Yes and Yes to both questions.

Answer (score 5):

Visa-free entry to the USA is only available if you are a **national** of a VWP country, *and* present a **passport issued by that country**.

A refugee travel document is, by definition, issued by a different country than the traveler's nationality -- so travelers on refugee documents are *never* eligible for visa-free entry.

Thus: You need a visa.